# SQLite RANDOM() Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, html, local-storage

I've got some JS that creates an SQLite database and inserts a little bit of data.

I've got a function that queries it and then spits out the resulting information as an alert.

If I try and get back a random field from the database I get no result (no obvious error either).

```
<title>Golf score keeper</title>

<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script>
  google.load("jquery", "1.4.1");
</script>

<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

    var db = window.openDatabase("scores", "", "Previous Scores", 1024*1000);

    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Strokes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, sample TEXT, sample2 TEXT)', []);
    });


    insertScores();
    extractScores()

  });

  function insertScores() {

    var example = "One";
    var example2 = "Two"; 

    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Strokes (sample, sample2) VALUES (?, ?)', [example, example2]);
    });


    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Strokes (sample, sample2) VALUES ("example3", "example4")', []);
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Strokes (sample, sample2) VALUES ("example5", "example6")', []);

    });
  }

  function extractScores() {

    db.transaction(function(tx) {

      //THIS ONE FAILS

     // tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM  Strokes ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;', [], displayResults);

      tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM  Strokes LIMIT 1;', [], displayResults);

    });
  }

  function displayResults(tx, rs){

        var $selectedAnswer = "";
          for (var i=0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) {
                var row = rs.rows.item(i);

            $selectedAnswer =($selectedAnswer + 'sample: ' + row['sample'] + ', sample2: ' + row['sample2']);
        }

        alert($selectedAnswer);
  }

</script>
```

Can anyone fathom this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've give it a run with Chrome.  RANDOM() is not supported as a function in the SQL Dialect. Same results in Firefox 4 Beta 9. The query is considered invalid!

Comment: RANDOM() is SQLite's version of RAND().

http://www.bernzilla.com/2008/05/13/selecting-a-random-row-from-an-sqlite-table/

So unless somehow I'm using it incorrectly that should work!

Comment: Sure, but the embedded version of sqlite in chrome/firefox doesn't support this function. Try to substitute RANDOM() with id and the query works!

Comment: Ahh, so what would the best way of getting a random row? Doing a count and using that as a max figure, using js to generate a random number from that , and using that random number in the query?

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to SQLite at all. ( Its just that SQLite is the SQL dialect implemented )
It's [HTML5 Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Example: [HTML5 Web Storage / localStorage](http://codebase.es/test/webstorage.html) ( click view source for more info )

Comment: Local storage is when you create local value pairs.

When you create an open database, you use SQLite - in webkit, gecko etc. (Read further down the link you sent me!)

Comment: It's a good example, but I want to use SQLite, not localstorage, they're two separate entities.

Answer (score 0):

I've not solved the problem, but I have created a work around.
As random doesn't work, and select count wouldn't give me a digit to play with, this is a long way around, but it will give us a random digit in which to query our database with.

```
    function finalScores() {

        //This gets a the last id in the table "Strokes", we'll use this to generate a random number
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
           tx.executeSql('SELECT id FROM  Strokes ORDER BY id DESC limit 1;', [], lastNumber);
        });
    }


    function lastNumber(tx, rs){

        var $lastNo = "";

            //This sets the last id as $lastNo to use later
            for (var i=0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) {
            var row = rs.rows.item(i);
            var $lastNo = row['id'];        
        }

    //This should be the last number    
    alert($lastNo);


    //We use this to avoid getting Zero as an answer

    function randomFromTo(from, to){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
    }
        //This generates a random number between [and including] 1 and your last number
        var $randomNum = randomFromTo(1, $lastNo);

    //This is our random number
    alert($randomNum);

    }
```